# Is there any relation between $F(-w)$ and $F(w)$ for the Fourier transform of $f(t)$?

Tags: fourier-transform, transformation, signal-processing, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to find out how to express $F(-w)$ in terms of $F(w)$ for the Fourier transform of $f(t)$. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If $x=F(w)$ then $F(-w)=F(-F^{-1}(x))$. I'm guessing that's not what you want, though. So you should be clearer about what your question is, and what it means to "express $F(-w)$ in terms of $F(w)$." Does this have something to do with the fact that if $F(w)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ then $F(-w)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $f(t)$?

Comment: One of the basic properties of the Fourier transform is $\;F(-\omega)=\overline{F(\omega)}\;$ ...Check it.

Comment: Yes @runway44 , what I meant was if F(w) is the Fourier transform of f(t), then what is the relation between F(w) and say F(-w).

Comment: Yes @runway44 , what I meant was if F(w) is the Fourier transform of f(t) then how are F(w) and F(-w) related.
I believe DonAntonio answered it. I tried checking the web for the properties of Fourier transform but couldn't find any relations between F(-w) and F(w).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio!

Comment: @DonAntonio That's true **IF** $f$ is real-valued, not in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition, and for real $\;f\;$ :

$$F(\omega)=\mathscr{F}\{f(x)\}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cos\omega xdx-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\sin\omega xdx$$

so

$$F(-\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i(-\omega x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{i\omega x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cos\omega xdx+i\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\sin\omega xdx=$$

$$=\overline{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cos\omega xdx-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\sin\omega xdx}=\overline{F(\omega)}$$

Comment: IF $f$ is real-valued

Comment: Indeed, David is correct. Just assumed $\;f\;$ is real because of the numerical optimization tag, but it could be a complex one, of course. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You can only work out a satisfactory formula when $f$ is real valued. In that case, we have that:

\begin{align}
\widehat{f}(-w) &= \int_\mathbb{R^n} f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot (-w)}\, dx \\
                &= \int_\mathbb{R^n} f(x)e^{2\pi i x w}\, dx \\
                &= \int_\mathbb{R^n} \overline{f(x)e^{-2\pi i x w}}\, dx \\
                &= \overline{\int_\mathbb{R^n} f(x)e^{2\pi i x w}\, dx} \\
                &= \overline{\widehat{f}(w)},
\end{align}

where the "real-value property" is used to go from line 2 to line 3.

This calculation shows that if $f$ is real-valued, then $\widehat{f}$ has a certain symmetry: an "inversion" in the argument results in a "conjugation" of the output. The same trick works to prove that if $f$ is purely imaginary, then $\widehat{f}(-w) = - \overline{\widehat{f}(w)}$, and one can make out simmilar arguments when one impose some restrictions on the values that $f$ can take.

However, we cannot hope to find any kind of symmetries for Fourier transforms of general complex-valued functions, since the Fourier transform is a bijection from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to itself. (In other words, if we apply the Fourier transform to a square-integrable function, the output can be "any" other square-integrable function, which of course could have no symmetry at all!!)

Of course it's possible to find some identities, such as $\widehat{f}(-w) = \overline{\widehat{\overline{f}}(w)}$ (the proof is the same as above), or $\widehat{f}(-w) = \widehat{\widehat{\widehat{f}}}(w)$, but they say nothing in particular about your question.